# White space appearing on side of website

Tags: html, css

I have a website and from out of nowhere, whitespace started appearing on the left hand side of the page. I just can't figure out what the issue is?

Please help. [Here is the link the the website](http://goo.gl/nGCkJ9)

Comment: Please upload an image or give more detail on where this whitespace you speak of resides.

Comment: Did you change the class from `container` to `no-container` on purpose? http://imgur.com/2jY19TP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.home #primary {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing overflow hidden removes the whitespace on the left, however the feature image is off.

```
.no-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow: hidden` from the `.no-container` class
Then you need to fix the slider position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this:

```
.no-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then adjust the settings for the Revolution Slider Wordpress plugin.  It looks like you have added an offset value as it automatically adds a `left` style to the element.  Also set the width to 100% it is currently set to 1663px and it should be ok.